# Poco example from the slides crashes

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I took this example code straight from the Poco site example documentation. It crashes before it reaches "2". Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// DatagramSocket send example
#include <Poco/Net/DatagramSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h>
#include <Poco/Timestamp.h>

#include <Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("localhost", 514);

    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;

    Poco::Net::DatagramSocket dgs(sa);

    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;

    std::string syslogMsg;
    Poco::Timestamp now;
    syslogMsg = Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(now,
                "<14>%w %f %H:%M:%S Hello, world!");

    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;

    dgs.sendBytes(syslogMsg.data(), syslogMsg.size());

    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}// DatagramSocket
```

Comment: See my comment to the answer below; a github issue has been created for this: https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/449

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the crash on my system. I added some exception handling to see what the problem was and it looked like the network wasn't being initialized (since I'm on Windows this means WSAStartup wasn't being called). Then there was an exception for the DatagramSocket not being connected. After making the following changes it worked for me.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// DatagramSocket send example
#include <Poco/Net/DatagramSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h>
#include <Poco/Timestamp.h>
#include <Poco/DateTimeFormatter.h>
#include <Poco/Net/NetException.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        Poco::Net::initializeNetwork();
        Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("localhost", 514);

        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;

        Poco::Net::DatagramSocket dgs;
        dgs.connect(sa);

        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;

        std::string syslogMsg;
        Poco::Timestamp now;
        syslogMsg = Poco::DateTimeFormatter::format(now,
            "<14>%w %f %H:%M:%S Hello, world!");

        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
        dgs.sendBytes(syslogMsg.data(), syslogMsg.size());
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;

        Poco::Net::uninitializeNetwork();
    }
    catch (const Poco::Net::NetException& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.displayText() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}// DatagramSocket
```

I don't know why the example didn't work as-is, but maybe the folks in the [Poco forums](http://pocoproject.org/forum/) could shed some light on it.

Comment: Network initialization (on Windows, since it is not needed elsewhere) is automatic since 1.5.2, see https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/include/Poco/Net/Net.h#L111 ; as for connecting the socket, sendBytes() does indeed require it to be connected (sendTo() can be used without calling connect, so the documentation example is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I have 1.4.6 so that explains the initialization difference. Thanks for the insight.